# How to find exact percentage of a value

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to set a percentage for a product.

Example - I bought a bike for 50000 and i increase the price by adding a percentage of 1%,the value ill get is 500.The total amount is 50500.

when i sell the bike i would like to give the bike by allowing a percentage of 1% at the price of 50500,the value i get is 505.The total amount after reducing 50500 - 505 = 40995.

I don't want to get the loss of 5 rupees after removing 1%.

what should i do to get 50000.

the code i use for percentage is

```
        double value = double.Parse(percentage_value);
        double percent = value / 100;
        percent = percent * double.Parse(amount);
        percentage = percent.ToString();
```

Comment: your question make no sense

Comment: You don't have a programming issue, you have a simple mathematics issue if you can't figure out why adding 1% to a value, then substracting 1% to the result doesn't give you the initial amount...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple mathematics issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple math problem, not a code related one.

50500 is 101% of the original price.

So 50500 / 101 * 100 = 50000

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep the "purchase value" and the percentage value applied during sell separated...

Comment: how can i do that ? any example ?

Comment: no example, simple keep the original bought value stored for future use. You don't have to calculate it from selling value and recharge percentage... it isn't a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

Simply add 1 to your `percent` value:

```
    double value = double.Parse(percentage_value);
    double percent = value / 100;
    percent = (1 + percent) * double.Parse(amount);
    var percentage = percent.ToString();
```

That will work for +ve and -ve percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
  double amount = 50500.00;
  double percent = 1.0;

  // price = 50000.0
  double price = (100.0 + percent) / 100.0 * amount; 
  // reduce
  double reduce = amount - percent;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple math.

Adding a percentage to a value is calculated by:

`old_value * 1.01 = new_value`.

This implies that getting back to the old value is calculated by:

`old_value = new_value / 1.01`

So simply change your code so that it calculates your values by the previous.

Comment: how can i use this code for 2% ? its multiplying the value n giving the answer as 100000

Comment: Adding 2% would be `old_value * 1.02 = new_value`